# Estimate Rotation and Translation from two sets of points in different coordinate systems

Tags: coordinate-systems, rotations

I got one set of 3d $(x,y,z)$ points (number of points $\geq3$) located in two different coordinate systems.
Is it possible to estimate the rotation and translation between these systems?

Something like
$$
        \begin{pmatrix}
        x_i' \\
        y_i'  \\
        z_i' \\
        \end{pmatrix}
=
        \begin{pmatrix}
        r_{11} & r_{12} & r_{13} \\
        r_{21} & r_{22} & r_{23}  \\
        r_{31} & r_{32} & r_{33} \\
        \end{pmatrix}
        \begin{pmatrix}
        x_i \\
        y_i  \\
        z_i \\
        \end{pmatrix}
+
        \begin{pmatrix}
        t_x \\
        t_y  \\
        t_z \\
        \end{pmatrix}
$$

$$i = 0,1,...,n$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 12 variables, $r_{ij}$s and $t_i$s. Each point gives 3 equations. So we need 4 points for unique solution to the matrices. Anything less, and you can have many solutions.

If you have more points than required you can try to use some estimation method like LSE.

Comment: aren't there 12 variables? 9 in the rotation matrix and 3 at the translation

Comment: oops.. my bad... There are only 12. 3x3+3. Sorry. I will edit the answer.

Comment: I got the linear equation now. But there is no solution for the translation t_x.
For the x it looks like this:

$$x_1*r_{11} + y_1 * r_{12} + z_1 * r_{13} + t_x = x'_1 $$
$$x_2*r_{11} + y_2 * r_{12} + z_2 * r_{13} + t_x = x'_2 $$
$$x_3*r_{11} + y_3 * r_{12} + z_3 * r_{13} + t_x = x'_3 $$
$$x_4*r_{11} + y_4 * r_{12} + z_4 * r_{13} + t_x = x'_4 $$

$$x_i, y_i, z_i, x'_i$$ are given.

Comment: What do you mean by "no solution"? If the transformed points are valid, there should be a solution.

Comment: You're right. The fault was on my side

Comment: This is incorrect - this ignores the orthogonal nature of $R$, which means you have only 3 variables for $R$, and $6$ all together

Comment: Since R is a rotation matrix, it is constrained to $R'R=I_3$ and $det(R)=1$, which gives 6 constraints, reducing the number of "free" parameters from 9 to 3.

Comment: @NathanielBubis Right That's where I started and missed during my edit. The original 9 I thought were needed, were 3 for rotation, 3 for translation and another 3 for scaling. So, $ R'R $ is a diagonal matrix.

Answer (score 2):

Wikipedia calls it [Kabsch algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kabsch_algorithm), based on:

KABSCH, Wolfgang. A solution for the best rotation to relate two sets of vectors. *Acta Crystallographica Section A: Crystal Physics, Diffraction, Theoretical and General Crystallography*, 1976, 32.5: 922-923.

KABSCH, Wolfgang. A discussion of the solution for the best rotation to relate two sets of vectors. *Acta Crystallographica Section A: Crystal Physics, Diffraction, Theoretical and General Crystallography*, 1978, 34.5: 827-828.

A recent exaplanation in [Least-Squares Rigid Motion Using SVD](https://igl.ethz.ch/projects/ARAP/svd_rot.pdf) by Olga Sorkine-Hornung and Michael Rabinovich.

Another reference is:
ARUN, K. Somani; HUANG, Thomas S.; BLOSTEIN, Steven D. Least-squares fitting of two 3-D point sets. *IEEE Transactions on pattern analysis and machine intelligence*, 1987, 5: 698-700.

If you do not know the [*correspondences*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correspondence_problem) between the points then you can apply a method called Iterative Closest Point (ICP):

BESL, P. J.; MCKAY, Neil D. A method for registration of 3-D shapes. *IEEE Transactions on Pattern Analysis and Machine Intelligence*, 1992, 14.2: 239-256.

CHEN, Yang; MEDIONI, Gérard. Object modelling by registration of multiple range images. *Image and vision computing*, 1992, 10.3: 145-155.

Answer (score 1):

You're missing one important point in the problem statement.  A coordinate translate preserves all point distances, and that implies that the "shape" of a point-cloud is preserved.  The same applies to coordinate rotation.  And, those two facts imply that shape is preserved under the combined T * R transform.

The implication is that there are stringent conditions on the dataset used as the input to the problem.  For the input points, a minimum of 3 are needed, and they must form a non-degenerate triangle.  But the greater constraint is on the "output" points...they must conform to the same rigid object shape (i.e. the same size and shape triangle).  If the input and output point clouds do not agree exactly in shape, there is no solution transform of the form T * R.

Answer (score 1):

Collect the *"set of points"* into **vectors**
$$
\def\qiq{\quad\implies\quad}
x_k=\pmatrix{x_k\\y_k\\z_k},\qquad
x'_k=\pmatrix{x'_k\\y'_k\\z'_k}
$$
Calculate the centroid of each group of vectors
$$c=\frac1n\sum_{k=1}^nx_k,\qquad c'=\frac1n\sum_{k=1}^nx'_k$$
Assuming that the rotation is with respect to the centroid $c,\,$ we have
$$c=Rc$$
which allows us to immediately solve for the translation vector
$$c' = (Rc+t) = (c+t) \qiq t = (c'-c)$$
For the next part, concatenate the vectors into matrices
$$\eqalign{
\def\m#1{\left[\begin{array}{r|r}#1\end{array}\right]}
X\:&=\m{x_1&x_2&\cdots} \\
X'&=\m{x'_1&x'_2&\cdots} \\
T\:&=\m{\;t\;\,&\;t\;&\cdots} \\
}$$
and write the whole problem in matrix form
$$\eqalign{
RX &= (X'-T) \;\doteq\; Y \\
}$$
This system is **overdetermined,** so we must solve it in
a least-squares sense
$$\eqalign{
\min_R\:&\left\|RX-Y\right\|^2_F \\
\operatorname{s.t.}\:&R^TR=I \\
}$$
This is the well-known [Orthogonal Procrustes Problem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonal_Procrustes_problem) whose solution utilizes the singular value decomposition of $YX^T$
$$YX^T = USV^T \qiq R = UV^T$$